# React.js - re-drawing array after update of item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have state like this:

```
this.state = {
  items = []
}
```

State is loaded from REST service, which is working correctly. 
However later , when user edit one of items in state, I use immutability helper to update state:

```
 const newState = update(this.state, {
            items: {
                [index]: {$set: newItem}
            }
  });
 this.setState(newState);
```

This will not be re-drawed (render method will pass , but no visible changes are made on page) and I know why:

Because I am creating array to render like this:

```
render(){
  let itemsrender=[];
  for (let i in this.state.items){
      let line="";
      if (i<this.state.items.length-1) line=<div className="row line"></div>;
            atcrender.push(
                <div key={this.state.item[i].id}>
                    <div className="row" >
                        <ITEM
                          item={this.state.items[i]}
                          onUpdate={this.onUpdate}
                          onDelete={this.onDelete}
                        />
                    </div>
                    {line}
                </div>
            )
        }
  return(
   <div>{itemsrender}</div>
  );

}
```

If I can not edit render method of ITEM , is there any solution I can make so item will re-render on update ? Only one that come to my mind is to create wrapping Component.

Comment: did you try to call `forceUpdate()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the issue is with the `let itemsrender` as this is what gets returned from the render method, this is all that will be rendered. You don't seem to update this anywhere in the loop so the return from the render method never changes.

You could also re-write this by mapping over the state and it might make it a bit easier to see whats going on.

```
render() {
     return (
       <div>
        {this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
          <div key={item.id}>
            <div className="row" >
              <ITEM
                item={item}
                onUpdate={this.onUpdate}
                onDelete={this.onDelete}
              />
            </div>
            {index < this.state.items.length - 1 ? <div className="row line"></div> : ''}
          </div>
        })}
       </div>
     )
   }
 }
```

Comment: Somehow this helped

Answer (score 0):

```
render(){
  let itemsrender=[];
  for (let i in this.state.items){
      let line="";
      if (i<this.state.items.length-1) line=<div className="row line"></div>;
          atcrender.push(
              <div key={this.state.item[i].id}>
                <div className="row" >
                        <ITEM
                        item={this.state.items[i]}
                          onUpdate={this.onUpdate}
                        onDelete={this.onDelete}
                      />
                  </div>
                  {line}
              </div>
          )
      }
  return(
   <div>{itemsrender}</div>
  );

}
```

Should `atcrender` on line 6, in fact be `itemsrender`? Or is there code elsewhere in this file that would reveal more about why you've done things this way?